# Create php math operation

Tags: php, math

How can i create a math operation in php and echoi the response:

I have `<?php echo $hotelPrices[3];?>` with ius the price without tax and i want add a 20% tax .
I have tried the below: but does not echo nothing

```
<?php
$pret1 =$hotelPrices[3];
echo ($pret1 * 0.20)."\n"; 
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$pret1 =$hotelPrices[3];
echo $pret1 + ($pret1 * 0.20); 
?>
```

Comment: This will always return 120.

Comment: @kos Do you know the value of $hotelPrices[3]?

Comment: I just wanted to show him how to add tax. Anyone can replace with any variable right? His problem is with math fn.

Comment: @Indra Kumar S No, is it 100?

Comment: Oh my god... Simple thing But unwanted conversation.. I did that edit... Stay relaxed

Comment: The $hotelPrices[3] its a dinamic value put i want to print a valua with 20% procent higher. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You just have to change `0.20` to `1.20`. So that it's 120% not 20% of the number like this:

```
echo ($pret1 * 1.20)."\n";
```